# Sending Signals in C?

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, handler

I read:

> There are two signals that a process can’t ignore – SIGKILL =
> terminate the receiving process – SIGSTOP = suspend the receiving
> process

And some even claimed there is no way we can declare handlers for them

But In C I can write:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void sigint_handler(int signum) {
    printf("I'm ignoring you!\n");
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGKILL,sigint_handler);
    for(;;) { /*endless loop*/ } return 0;
}
```

Isn't this a contradiciton?

Side Question, When I write `kill 123` in the terminal what signal will be sent I can't find this information anywhere in the internet?

Comment: *"When I write kill 123 in the terminal what signal will be sent I can't find this information anywhere in the internet?"* - The [man 1 kill](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) is stating *"If no signal is specified, the **TERM** signal is sent"*

Comment: What was the return value of the `signal(SIGKILL,sigint_handler);` call? And if it returns `SIG_ERR`, what is the value of `errno`?

Comment: Trying with both `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` fails, you just don't check the return value: https://onlinegdb.com/J9c-6_5LZ

Comment: Writing code that tries to do something illegal doesn't necessarily mean the code cannot be compiled – consequences might only come into effect as late as during runtime...

Comment: what happens when you actually send the signal? Does it print "I'm ignoring you!"? Or does it stop running?

Comment: Default signal in `kill` command, is 15 (SIGTERM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [POSIX-1.2017 General Information §2.4.3 Signal Actions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03)
, a signal may have one of three different dispositions or "actions taken" when it is delivered to a process:

- SIG_DFL: take the default or "normal" action.
- SIG_IGN: ignore the signal (take no action).
- *user-defined*: the signal is "caught" by a user-defined signal handler.

That said, the same section of POSIX also clarifies:

> The system shall not allow the action for the signals SIGKILL or SIGSTOP to be set to SIG_IGN.
>
> ....
> The system shall not allow a process to catch the signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP.

If you checked the return code and *errno* of your `signal()` call, you'd almost certainly see it [failing with EINVAL](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html#tag_16_550_05).